# Is there a better way than a LEFT JOIN to join two tables together in MYSQL? It is extremely slow

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `imdbID` varchar(9),
  `title` varchar(255),
  KEY `imdbID` (`imdbID`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `move_ratings` (
  `imdbID` varchar(9),
  `user` varchar(36),
  `multiplier` float,
  KEY `imdbID` (`imdbID`),
  KEY `user_uuid` (`user_uuid`)
)
```

The MOVIES table has about 200,000 records and the MOVIE_RATINGS table has about 20,000 records.

When I do a LEFT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT m.imdbid, mr.multiplier 
    FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN movie_ratings mr
    ON mr.imdbID = m.imdbID AND mr.user = :user;
```

It takes something like 11 minutes. I would think that this query would take a few seconds at most. But I'm new to MYSQL and I'm sure I am missing something, probably simple.

Comment: Create composite index `move_ratings (user, imdbID)`. PS. Why the join is LEFT, not INNER?

Comment: I want to add every MOVIE record whether there is a MOVIE_RATINGS record or not. Does that make sense? I just tried it with an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN and it was really fast (after creating the composite index--thank you!). But I'm not sure I'm getting all of the MOVIE records. I will have to check

Comment: *I want to add every MOVIE record whether there is a MOVIE_RATINGS record or not.* Ok, in such case LEFT is correct... but take into account that the output rowset will contain 200k rows, so it may be long not only because of long execution but also because of long output rowset transferring to the client.

Comment: I'm wondering if I have some kind of corruption in the database. If I EXPLAIN the exact same query with INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN I get totally different results. Notably, the INNER JOIN "type" is "ref" and "eq_ref" while the LEFT JOIN (with everything else the same) is type "index" and "all"

Comment: This is another and separate question - you may create new topic if you really need in this.